# how to apply a for loop to a os.path.join()

Tags: python

I want to automatically send the newly generated figures from scanning machine by email. First, I watch which files are newly created. And then send them by email. so I need the file location for my email.
I meet a problem about using the for loop to a string generated by os.path.join(), the for loop separates every character from the os.path.join(), it is not what I want.
Do you have any good ideas? thanks

```
import os
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(minutes=30)

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('D:\my_python\small script'):  
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
           if fname.endswith(('.jfif', '.jpg', 'TIFF')):
               new_picture = fname
               pathnew = os.path.join(root, new_picture)

               for path_new in pathnew:
               print(path_new)
```

I expect output like this :

```
D:\my_python\small script\123\image1.jfif
D:\my_python\small script\123\image2.jfif
```

but the current for loop goes this:

```
D
:
\
m
y
_
p
y
t
h
o
n
\
s
m
a
l
l

s
c
r
i
p
t
\
1
2
3
\
i
m
a
g
d
.
j
f
i
f
```

How to solve it? thanks

Comment: You need to use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20listdir#os.listdir) to actually get the list of files. How did you expect to get the files by iterating a string?

Comment: ^ Exactly, I see the string being iterated.

Comment: drop `for file in path:` loop, just print `path` => done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to intialize path a as list then append path.

```
path=[]
for root, dirs,files in os.walk('D:\my_python\small script'):  
    for fname in files:
        path.append(os.path.join(root, fname))
for x in path:print(x)
```

Comment: thanks for answering my low questions. thanks a lot.